# Redirecting Posts on Tumblr to Custom Pages

Tags: html, tumblr

Now before you post one of the many "Add a Page" tutorials I've read, I'm going to say that none of those have helped because not only has Tumblr removed the "Redirect" option on it (courtesy of April 8th, 2015, unfortunately), but the add a page feature does not seem to work when using a custom HTML code--even when you use the "add a page" link that you created and paste it into the link url section provided for the tabs!

Of course, I have also looked at questions on here, but those pertain to loops leading back to the Home page, and do not specify how to have your posts redirected to a specific page. Believe me, I have tried the whole /tagged/yourname URLS under the URL section for the Link, but that is ineffective. I have even tried giving the post a Custom URL and then pasting that URL into the designated link URL section to see if it would pop up under the page but alas, that did not work either. And yes, I've even scoured through the code to find a possible paste solution and have pasted the link into the code directly, but that didn't change anything either as it was just under the "naming" section in the beginning of the code, anyways (should've known that wouldn't work).

If anyone can help me with this issue, or at least understand what I'm even asking, I would be forever grateful.

**EFFORT FURTHER EXPLAINED**:

**Note**: the tumblr's /submit URL works, but my attempts on, for eg, a separate art page for posts tagged "somethingart" have been fails.

Redirect: [Here's](http://tutorialmaster.tumblr.com/post/18105267257/how-to-make-a-redirect-page-on-your-blog) an example of one of the many tutorials I read that has a clear image of where the "redirect" option should be, but of course it's outdated as the edit appearance looks slightly different from that now (you have to scroll down a little).

**Okay, so let's move on to the other attempts now although, unfortunately, you're going to have to view them on a [google document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wAKDeRKiEcFOCFkyKilEgukeY28Q7pMSSl24atuxpm4/edit?usp=sharing) because apparently, you need to have 10+ reputation to post more than two links (click the link above)!**

As for the coding part, well I'm actually a beginner at coding as I've only had two classes last semester (which was a while ago), and that was in C# and the foundations of computer science, so scouring through this code to try and find where I could add something to make it work only gave me a headache in the end (it's really long...).

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: The world is not against you or something, focus more on describing the issue, with codes you tried, thank you! Also Tumblr did not remove the "Redirect" option from type of pages you can make, it is exactly where it was and works as it supposed to. Just a link inside a post can not redirect you to another page.

Comment: I think I understand your first paragraph and what might be the problem. Please explain your second paragraph better.

Comment: It is possible, with the custom redirect that is part of tumblr architecture. If you want a particular page to redirect somewhere else, it is also possible to achieve this via a hosted script. Check here: `http://madox-test.tumblr.com/` there is a link to an item 'bespoke'. If you inspect the url it merely points to /bespoke but redirects to /tagged/bespoke (tumblr redirect). And on this page `http://madox-test.tumblr.com/test-redirect` I have linked to a script which contains the following: `window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");` So clearly it is possible.

Comment: To manetsus, I was originally going to show my effort, except that it would be a lot of screen-shoting that would make for one long post. However, I see that the screen-shoting is necessary now to better explain the second paragraph, as mentioned by Lokait, and therefore show lharby that what he answered was something that I knew, but is not what I really wanted. Give me a moment to update the question, please (as this is going to be a little while)!

Comment: Okay, the question has been updated and is more complex now! I hope this helps (it took about 2 hours to do, too)...!

Comment: You still can not find the  "Redirect" (page type) option after you click on "Add a Page"? What happens when you click on "Standard Layout"? Did you notice there is a arrow pointing down?

Comment: Okay I see your pictures, the reason the "Redirect" option is not there; "If you don’t see this option, don’t fret — to prevent spam, we unlock features over time for new accounts. Once you’ve used Tumblr for a while to follow blogs, like posts, and customize your blog, this feature will be unlocked for you." [source](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/blog_customization#pagesfaq). Always check the official Documentations.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get you now. As a new account some features are not yet available to you. You will get those features eventually. For now (from what you have in the pictures):

The link (link6 URL) went to home page (or to the error page) most probably because you did not have `http://` in the beginning. I said that by assuming how your theme is made based on the picture of 'Theme Options'.

After that is solved, you know the page would not redirect itself to your "tagged/something" page because it is not a "Redirect" page, and you do not have any script to do the redirection (if you do not actually).

Do not worry though, there is a better way; just have the "tagged/something" link directly in your "*Link6 URL*" option (as in the pictures). You have to put it something like; `http://yourblog.tumblr.com/tagged/something`.

Let me know if you have any questions?

Comment: oh my goodness, I cannot believe that I missed something so simple as that. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Such a simple mistake that I kept looking over, and that was the answer all along....I feel so silly now for even spending two hours explaining this ridiculous question...

Comment: Actually I would not get what the problem is if your did not explain more with screenshots. Yes everything could be just in one paragraph, but you were probably confused, happens. If this answered your question, you can accept it, then it will appear as solved.